# Loop multiple URLs to parse with REGEX URLLIB in Python3.4

Tags: parsing, urllib, python-3.4

I am currently parsing data from `yahooFinance` using regex and `urllib`.  I could write a parsing function for each URL, but I would rather use an if statement to declare which URL to use depending on which stat I am looking for.  My current code is below.

## QUESTION 1

How can I link each stat variable at the bottom of the code (rt, capExp) to the list statName so I can use the if statement to declare the correct URL in the urllib function.

## QUESTION 2

Which data structure would be best to use for `statName` if not a list?

## CODE

```
def parseFinData():


    def urlGenerate():
        for ticker in index:

            newIsUrl = isUrl.replace('AAPL', ticker)
            newBsUrl = bsUrl.replace('AAPL', ticker)
            newCfUrl = cfUrl.replace('AAPL', ticker)

            statName = ['capExp','rt']
            
            if len(statName) == 2:
                url = newBsUrl
            elif len(statName) == 6:
                url = newCfUrl
            else:
                url = newIsUrl


            req = urllib.request.Request(url)
            resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
            respData = resp.read()

            rt = re.findall('Retained Earnings</td><td align="right">(.*?)&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>', dRespData)

            capExp = re.findall('Capital Expenditures</td><td align="right">(.*?)</td>', dRespData)
```